# Как обращаться к элементам массива, чтобы индексом была строка?

Tags: delphi

Подскажите, как создать, и можно ли, массив где индексом будет строка?`MyArray['index']`?

Если невозможно, то что за структура у `TIBQuery` с ее обращением `IBQ['some_field_name']` ?

Comment: для таких целей обычно используют `TStringList`. а-ля `sl.values['index'] := 'qwe';`

Comment: либо `TDictionary<string, T>` из `Generics.Collections`

Comment: а само обращение такое, можно реализовать и вручную.

Comment: У `TIBQuery` свойство [] обьяслено индексным с строковым аргументом индекса. А уже внутри его вызывается что-то вроде `FieldIndexByName()`.

Comment: @nick_n_a "обьявлено индексным с строковым аргументом индекса." Где вы это увидели, я тоже так хочу!!! Вопрос в том и заключается как сделать аналогичную конструкцию!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Сами по себе массивы не поддерживают строковые ключи. Однако, есть множество структур, которые предлагают такой функционал. Одним из распространенных решений для хранений пар ключ-значение, используемых в компонентах являются различные наследники класса `TStrings` и наиболее часто используемый из них - `TStringList` из модуля `classes`.

```
sl := TStringList.Create();
try
    sl.values['index'] := 'qwe';
    writeln(sl.Values['index']);
finally
    sl.Free();
end;
```

В целом же основной структурой данных в похожих ситуациях является словарь `TDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Это обобщенный (дженерик, generics, шаблонный) тип с параметризованными типами ключей и значений. Например, для хранения строковых ключей и целочисленных значений можно использовать следующий код.

```
d := TDictionary<string, integer>.Create();
try
    d.AddOrSetValue('key', 123);
    writeln(d['key']);
finally
    d.Free();
end;
```

Словари, наравне со списками `TList`, стэком `TStack` и очередями `TQueue` являются основным структурами хранения данных. Их функционал достаточно обширен.

Что касается индексированного доступа к некоторым данным объекта это может быть реализовано и вручную в любом классе.
Для  этого необходимо реализовать индексное свойство, и добавить к нему модификатор `default`. Очевидно, что default-свойство, позволяющее не указывать имя свойства при обращении, может быть только одно.

```
TTest = class(TObject)
  private
     function getValue(key:string):integer;
     procedure setValue(key: string; value: integer);
  public
    property Values[key: string]: integer read getValue write setValue; default;
end;
```

Реализацию методов `get/set-value` оставим максимально простой.

```
function TTest.getValue(key: string):integer;
begin
    result := 123;
end;

procedure TTest.setValue(key:string; value : integer);
begin
    raise Exception.Create('not implemented');
end;
```

В данной реализации любое обращение по строковому ключу будет возвращать значение `123`:

```
t := TTest.Create();
try
    writeln(t['index']);

finally
    t.Free();
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!

Comment: зачем пустные скобки () в Create & Free? Оне не нужны

Comment: @Zam дело вкуса. я всегда пишу скобки у методов, мне так нагляднее в коде различать вызовы методов от возможных обращений к переменным.